# For loop randomly stopping and not working

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, debugging

I'm writing a program to grab all of the `md5sums` of a certain file but it stops around 40,000. Any help would be great, here is my program.

NOTE: 40,000 has no meaning other than it just breaks there.

```
def grabmd5():
    for x in range(0, numLinesofFile):
        f = open(finfile1, 'r')
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            os.system("md5sum " + line + " 2>/dev/null" + " >> file2.txt")
    if x == numLinesofFile:
        print("It worked")
```

Comment: What is `size` holding? That `break` is an obvious culprit (I'm assuming that's supposed to be part of the loop. Please fix the indentation). You won't see that `print` since you're breaking before it. Also note, `else: continue` is unnecessary. The code would behave identically without it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the help. Lol I know my coding practice is very bad, I fixed it to make more clear, Although I am still geting the issue. Any other help would be good!

Comment: line 5 is meant to be indented, right?